Using hidden functions when defining a new method for a generic in R
I want to create a new subclass of the mesh3d S3 object class, and a corresponding method for rgl::shade3d. The new method will be closely modelled on the existing shade3d function but with different defaults. This is what I tried initially:
library(rgl)

# Create a test object
obj <- translate3d(tetrahedron3d(col = "red"), 0, 0, 0)

# Create a new S3 subclass 
obj <- structure(obj, class = c("myclass", "mesh3d", "shape3d"))

# Creating a shade3d method for myclass
shade3d.myclass <- function(mesh, ...) {
  shade3d(mesh, ..., lit = F)
}

shade3d(obj)
# Error: C stack usage  15923488 is too close to the limit

As far as I can figure out, this is because the function tries to call itself. To prevent this, I need to specify the method I'm referring to within my function.
methods(shade3d)
# [1] shade3d.mesh3d*      shade3d.myclass      shade3d.shapelist3d*

shade3d.myclass <- function(mesh, ...) {
  rgl:::shade3d.mesh3d(mesh, ..., lit = F)
}

shade3d(obj)

This now works. But I've read that using ::: to make use of hidden functions from another package is not good practice. Presumably it has been set as hidden for a reason. Do I have any other options here? Is this an acceptable use case for :::?

If you are just changing defaults, try NextMethod(mesh, ..., lit = FALSE) instead.

If you are just changing defaults, try NextMethod instead.
# Creating a shade3d method for myclass
shade3d.myclass <- function(mesh, ...) {
  NextMethod(mesh, ..., lit = FALSE)
}

Or even better, be user-friendly and set the defaults in the function definition.
# Creating a shade3d method for myclass
shade3d.myclass <- function(mesh, ..., lit = FALSE) {
  NextMethod(mesh, ..., lit = lit)
}


Yes, that seems to be what I was looking for! I have simplified down for the sake of the example, there is some other processing that goes on prior to the shade3d.mesh3d call, but I've tested it out and it still does the job. And thanks for the tip about setting defaults, that's a good point.

When you say "if you are just changing defaults", did you have a situation in mind when this approach would not work?

@user2390246 No I don't. That's another reason why I find the 2nd version better.
